# Should client side should have a separate server?

Tags: node.js, angular, tomcat, gulp

Hi we are developing web application angular js for front end the server side is spring framework and our server is tomcat all is in single file. When hit a request from postman i am getting response immediately. but when i do it in angular js the response timing is too late. sometimes i am getting instantly but most of the time the response is too late.

Shall i extract a web page from tomcat and use with node or gulp does tat help me get a fast response.

What is the best option the client should have the seprate server i need some solution..

Comment: build your ng apps with "ng build --prod"

Comment: Why would you want to have two servers? 1. Spring. 2. NodeJs. Spring will do the work just fine

Comment: Look at the tab "Network" on developer tools, and for this specific request try to see where is the delay. If it is during waiting, downloading, requesting, etc.

Comment: The problem is getting in network tab the request seems to be pending or even sometimes the request getting 200 status but response is not coming .